# not able to use the comparator in my program

Tags: java, comparator, treeset

In this program it is not identifying the `compartor`, I don't want to use the `compareTo`.

```
class TestTreeSet
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        BuildObject build = new BuildObject();
        TreeSet treeSet = new TreeSet( new Compared());
        treeSet = build.sendAsTreeSet();
        Iterator itr = treeSet.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            Obj object = (Obj) itr.next();
            System.out.println(object.getName() + "\n " + object.getAge() + "\n "
                 + object.getSalary());
        }
    }
}
```

this is the comparator

```
class Compared implements Comparator
{
    public int compare(Object a , Object b)
    {
        Obj one = (Obj) a;
        Obj two = (Obj) b;
        double salaryOne = one.getSalary();
        double salaryTwo = two.getSalary();
        int ageOne = one.getAge();
        int ageTwo = two.getAge();
        if( ageOne == ageTwo)
        {
            if(salaryOne > salaryTwo)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else if(salaryOne < salaryTwo)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else return 0;
        }
        else if(ageOne > ageTwo)
        return -1;
        else return 1;
    }
}
```

what is the problem ? it shows cannot be cast to `java.lang.comparable` exception

Comment: 1. why ur assigning `treeSet = build.sendAsTreeSet();` 2. why you have raw `TreeSet` ?

Comment: am using raw treeset because i am yet to learn generics

Comment: then you need to create a `new TreeSet` with that collection.. what is the return type of `build.sendAsTreeSet()` ?

Comment: where are you getting the exception, which line?

Comment: the return type of build.sendAsTreeSet() is a TreeSet - sanbhat , 
the exception is in the 10th line - abu

Comment: What is line 10? how is the treeset retuned by `sendAsTreeSet` populated? can you post that code?

Comment: public TreeSet sendAsTreeSet()
 {

  TreeSet treeSet = new TreeSet();
  List list = build();
  Iterator itr = list.iterator();
  while(itr.hasNext())
  {
   Obj object = (Obj) itr.next();
   if(object.getName().equals("Akhilesh") || object.getName().equals("Shriram") || object.getName().equals("Nagi") || object.getName().equals("Harish") || object.getName().equals("Vignesh") || object.getName().equals("Ram") || object.getName().equals("Kailash") || object.getName().equals("Sujith"))
   treeSet.add(object);

  }

  return treeSet;
 }

Comment: thanks i found the mistake

Comment: i didnt add the comparator in the sendAsTreeSet() program.. that was the mistake. thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

> A NavigableSet implementation based on a TreeMap. The elements are ordered **using their natural ordering**, or by a Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

Emphasis mine.

You might think you pass a `Comparator`, so the natural ordering is not used. But in this line

```
treeSet = build.sendAsTreeSet();
```

you overwrite the `treeSet` you just created in the previous line. That tree set most likely doesn't have a `Comparator` set.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Make sure that the treeset returned by `build` has a `Comparator` set (based on your comment, use `new TreeSet(new Compared())` in that method).
2. Make sure that the elements in the treeset returned by `build` implement `Comparable`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use

```
TreeSet treeSet = new TreeSet();
```

in your `sendAsTreeSet` method, the treeset tries to sort the elements added using theire [natural ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). Witch impiles the class of your objects musst implement the [Compareable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.

You should replace that line with

```
TreeSet treeSet = new TreeSet( new Compared());
```

The same line in the main method can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think its

```
implements Comparable
```

So just have to change it to the correct interface

Comment: i dont want to use comparable here.. i want to use the comparator to sort, its kind of a project to use only comparator

Comment: Can you please show the error message or some output about the error?

Comment: the error is - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException : Obj cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Comment: This means you can you only compare Objects that implement the interface Comparable. And the objects you want to compare are not of this type. Strange project setup, i would advise you to enable the use of Comparable interface. I never heared about disadvantages of their use.

Comment: i think i found the problem, i didnt add the comparator to the sendAsTreeSet() method in the other program. thanks for the help

Comment: Could you please answer your question then, when the minimum waiting time is over? ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
BuildObject build = new BuildObject();
TreeSet treeSet = new TreeSet( new Compared());
treeSet = build.sendAsTreeSet();
```

If `sendAsTreeSet` method return s a `TreeSet` which contains object of type `Obj` class then, you can change the `ComparedClass` as following, i hope it works.

```
class Compared implements Comparator
{
public int compare(Obj a , Obj b)
{

    double salaryOne = a.getSalary();
    double salaryTwo = b.getSalary();
    int ageOne = a.getAge();
    int ageTwo = b.getAge();
    if( ageOne == ageTwo)
    {
        if(salaryOne > salaryTwo)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if(salaryOne < salaryTwo)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else return 0;
    }
    else if(ageOne > ageTwo)
    return -1;
    else return 1;
}
}
```

Comment: This won't work. The problem is that `sendAsTreeSet()` overwrites the original `treeSet`, so the reference to the `Comparator` is completely lost.

Comment: The you have to get those list of `Obj` objects here and insert those to `Treeset` object

Answer (score 0):

When you are overriding or adding collection to collection(Treeset) you need your elements or class to implement comparable by comparator used in later collection.

Try implementing comparable on your element class as below

```
class Person implements Comparable{

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

and instead to assigning reference by

```
treeSet = build.sendAsTreeSet();
```

use addAll as below

```
treeSet.addAll(build.sendAsTreeSet());
```

Hope will above work for you. Please let me know if it didnt work

check below sample

```
public class ComparatorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TreeSet<Person> treeSet = new TreeSet<Person>(new Comparator());
        treeSet.addAll(new BuildObject().sendAsTreeSet());
        Iterator<Person> itr = treeSet.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            Person itrObject =  itr.next();
            System.out.println("Name: "+itrObject.getName()+"\n Age: "+itrObject.getAge() + "\n Salary: " + itrObject.getSalary());
        }
    }
}

class Comparator implements java.util.Comparator<Person> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person one, Person two) {
        double salaryOne = one.getSalary();
        double salaryTwo = two.getSalary();
        int ageOne = one.getAge();
        int ageTwo = two.getAge();
        if (ageOne == ageTwo) {
            if (salaryOne > salaryTwo) {
                return -1;
            } else if (salaryOne < salaryTwo) {
                return 1;
            } else
                return 0;
        } else if (ageOne > ageTwo)
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    }
}

class BuildObject{
    public TreeSet<Person> sendAsTreeSet(){
        Person object = new Person();
        object.setName("Pritesh");
        object.setAge(20);
        object.setSalary(1000);

        Person object2 = new Person();
        object2.setName("Joe");
        object2.setAge(19);
        object2.setSalary(3000);

        Person object3 = new Person();
        object3.setName("Blogg");
        object3.setAge(20);
        object3.setSalary(4000);

        TreeSet<Person> treeSet =  new TreeSet<Person>();
        treeSet.add(object);
        treeSet.add(object2);
        treeSet.add(object3);
        return treeSet;
    }
}

class Person implements Comparable{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int salary;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first statement is wrong. If you use a Comparator in the TreeSet you do not need the elements to have a natural ordering.